# How get an Y position on a Polygon

Tags: java, coordinates, polygon

I have a polygon in a 2d game in Java. How can I get an Y-position on the polygon, from a given X-position on the polygon.

See picture:

[image: Game, polygon]

I want to place the player on the cross, but I dont know how to get out a Y position thats on the polygon.

Here's some more info, the polygon is of type, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html.

Here's how it's created:

```
 private void paintGround(Graphics2D g2d){
    int width =  gameBoard.getWidth(); //1000
    int height = gameBoard.getHeight(); //750
    int xCoords[] = {0,0,width/2,width,width};
    int yCoords[] = {height,height/2,height/2-100,height/2,height};
    g2d.setColor(Color.white);
    Polygon polygon = new Polygon(xCoords, yCoords,5);
    g2d.fillPolygon(polygon);
    }
```

Thanks for your time and sorry for the stupid question :)

Here's the git, if anyone is interested:
https://github.com/davli921/Smrow.git

Comment: I'm not sure that your question makes sense; any X coordinate may have multiple Y coordinates, hence why the coordinate system is **2D**. From what I can see, your landscape is essentially a series of "height" coordinates, rather than a free-form polygon, so you'd simply need to use linear interpolation to get the height of a point between two vertices.

Comment: It depends on what class the polygon is. Care to add that to your question?

Comment: It's pretty simple, if you consider the top of your polygon as two straight lines, then `Y = a*X+b`. Just have to compute `a` and `b` for the left part and the right part :)

Comment: If you tell us the coordinates of the 5 corners we can easily answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a more general solution for getting the height at a particular point between two vertices:

- Define the "mountains" as an array, with the *indices* representing the `X` values and the actual *contents* representing the `Y` (height) values.
- Use this information to calculate the Y position for the "player" based on their current `X` value.
- Draw the results.

The example below has been implemented in Javascript so that anyone can easily try it out in their browser, but the principle is the same no matter what language you are using. First we need to define some basic HTML, so that we have a canvas to draw to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="game_canvas" width="400" height="300">You must enable Javascript</canvas>
    <script src="game.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, here's the important part - the Javascript:

```
"use strict";

// This series of points represents the "height" values of the landscape.
var points = [10, 50, 150, 20, 100, 10];

// Let's pick a random X position...
var x = Math.random() * (points.length-1);

// We can get the height at a given point by interpolating the vertices:
var v1 = points[Math.floor(x)];
var v2 = points[Math.ceil(x)];
var y = v1 + ((v2-v1) * (x % 1.0));

// Now let's draw the "game" state...
var canvas = document.getElementById("game_canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x_scale = canvas.width / points.length;

// This is the "world"...
ctx.moveTo(0, points[0]);
for (var p = 1; p < points.length; ++p) { ctx.lineTo(x_scale * p, points[p]); }
ctx.stroke();

// ...and this is the "player".
ctx.fillStyle = "red";  
ctx.fillRect((x * x_scale)-4, y-4, 8, 8);
```

Save these files to a local folder (ensuring that the JS file is saved as `game.js`) and open the HTML file in your browser:

[image]

Press **F5** to refresh the page (and thus pick a new random `X` position).